# NetBeans: accessing class from MyAppView.java

Tags: netbeans6.8

When I add an actionperformed event to a button, it generates the TODO section.

However, I would like for it to call a public method defined in MyApp.java, instead of having to define the method inside the MyAppView.java

How can I do this ? Tell MyAppView.java to get the methods and classes from MyApp.java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correcty:
MyApp.java should implement ActionListener interface, then when creating button. Add object of the class MyApp to listen for actions on this button.

```
button.addActionListener(myApp);
```